# Sharing Raw Kernel Cache between Docker Containers

Tags: docker, cupy

I'm creating a python application that uses `cupy.RawKernal`. The application runs within a docker container using NVIDIA Container Toolkit. I'd like to avoid having the `cupy.RawKernal` recompile every time I create a new container (happens frequently in development).

I've setup a volume mount like so:

`docker run --runtime=nvidia -v ${HOME}/.cupy/kernel_cache:/home/app/.cupy/kernel_cache -d docker_image`

After running the application, I see the `.cubin` files in their respective locations in the container and on the host. However when I recreate the container, it still takes much longer to startup the first time it is run. The `.cubin` files also do not get updated on the host or the container.

My first thought was a permissions issue, I've given full R/W permissions on the host folder with no effect.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: When you run in the docker, is `$HOME` equal to `/home/app` at Python runtime? If not, you may try setting `CUPY_CACHE_DIR=/home/app/.cupy/kernel_cache` and see how it goes. There could be other reasons impacting the speed of first runs, so I wouldn't say for sure it's due to kernel cache without a proper timing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tracked the slowdown to the first call into the cupy library. `cp.arange`. This first time this is run, it generates a cubin file in the cache directory in the container and the host. When run in a new container this call takes the same amount of time to run, leading me to believe that the cache is not being used

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there is a second cache folder that needs to be shared:

`~/.nv/ComputeCache`

For more information, please see this link:
https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-understand-fat-binaries-jit-caching/

### JIT Caching

The second approach to mitigate JIT overhead is to cache the binaries generated by JIT compilation. When the device driver just-in-time compiles PTX code for an application, it automatically caches a copy of the generated binary code to avoid repeating the compilation in later invocations of the application. The cache—referred to as the *compute cache*—is automatically invalidated when the device driver is upgraded, so that applications can benefit from improvements in the just-in-time compiler built into the device driver.

Environment variables are available to control just-in-time compilation.

- Setting `CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE` to 1 disables caching (no binary code is added to or retrieved from the cache).
- `CUDA_CACHE_MAXSIZE` specifies the size of the compute cache in bytes; the default size is 256 MiB (since NVIDIA driver release 334, 32 MiB before), and the maximum size is 4 GiB; binary codes whose size exceeds the cache size are not cached; older binary codes are evicted from the cache to make room for newer binary codes if needed.
- `CUDA_CACHE_PATH` specifies the directory location of compute cache files; the default values are:

  `CUDA_CACHE_PATH` specifies the directory location of compute cache files; the default values are:

  on Windows, `%APPDATA\%NVIDIA\ComputeCache`,

  on MacOS, `$HOME/Library/Application Support/NVIDIA/ComputeCache`,

  on Linux, `~/.nv/ComputeCache`

  Setting `CUDA_FORCE_PTX_JIT` to 1 forces the device driver to ignore any binary code embedded in an application (see Application Compatibility) and to just-in-time compile embedded PTX code instead. If a kernel does not have embedded PTX code, it will fail to load. You can use this environment variable to confirm that an application binary contains PTX code and that just-in-time compilation works as expected to guarantee forward compatibility with future architectures.